# How to debug Quasar Electron App with VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, electron, quasar-framework

I'm having a hard time configuring vs code to debug an electron app.
What I'm trying to do is to build the project with the `-d` option to generate the debug (https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/cli-documentation/commands-list#build)

And then using the following vscode launch config:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "name": "Electron Main",
            // "preLaunchTask": "npm: quasar build -m electron",
            "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/electron",
            "windows": {
                "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/electron.cmd"
            },
            "args" : ["."],
            "outputCapture": "std",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/dist/electron/UnPackaged/electron-main.js"
        }
    ]
}
```

This doesn't work. The program starts but every breakpoint gets "unverified" and it is not hit. Probably because, as far as I know, quasar uses babel to transpile files or something like that. I think I'm missing some configs. Any ideas how can I debug it?

Comment: Have you tried `"args" : [".", "-d"]`? I'm not sure what "unverified" means but it doesn't look like you are passing the debug argument

Comment: Unverified means the breakpoints is greyed-out in the vs code and it is not hit. I haven't tried those args. Will do!

Comment: @JoãoMenighin, I'm unfamiliar with Quasar. However, with this configuration, you can only debug code running in the main process. If the code is running in a renderer process, you're going to have to use the chrome dev tools. vscode breakpoints will never hit.